# How to pass grid operations like filtering, sorting, grouping and paging to Web API service?

Tags: c#, rest, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

The problem is that I want to have best performance for Kendo grid (or other clients like an Android app) operations like filtering, sorting, pagination, and grouping. So I have to create a Web API action like:

```
public JsonResult Get(a filter, b sort, c group, d pageSize, e skip, f take)
```

The filter needs to be able to query some relational objects, for example:

```
student=>student.Father.Name == "James"
```

This should be true also for grouping and also sorting.

What is the correct way?

I have read a lot about Dynamic Linq and also OData.  But both seems not as popular and performant as JSON. Also another problem is the difference between Grid View Model and Domain POCOs.

The Web API method tends to be for general usage and not just for Kendo grid.

Comment: We have that implementation in one of our projects and I must tell you, it is not trivial as it seems so, in fact it is very complex to achieve. These kendo control objects are nested and recursive, its kinda tricky to translate that to Linq. We use `PredicateBuilder` here to achieve that.

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/binding/web-api-server-operations